# Replacing a pattern with awk or sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file with patterns like below

```
12345343|559|-2,0,-200000,-20|20161108000000|FL|62,859,1439,1956|0,0,21300,0|S
3434344|-100000|20161108000000|GL|135|0|S
45454545|214|-2000,-2,0,0,-20|20161108000001||21,62,859,969,1956|77440,0,0,0,0|S
```

Here I need to replace all the `,` values and get the first value in the sub set

Required output:

```
12345343|559|-2|20161108000000|FL|62|0|S
3434344|-100000|20161108000000|GL|135|0|S
45454545|214|-200000|20161108000001||21|77440|S
```

I have tried `sed 's/\,*|//'` but didnt work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: Looks like you meant to write `,[^|]*` rather than `\,*|`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, simplest of all:

```
$ sed 's/,[^|]*//g' ip.txt 
12345343|559|-2|20161108000000|FL|62|0|S
3434344|-100000|20161108000000|GL|135|0|S
45454545|214|-2000|20161108000001||21|77440|S
```

Just replace `,` followed by non`|` characters with nothing

Same with `perl`

```
$ perl -pe 's/,[^|]*//g' ip.txt 
12345343|559|-2|20161108000000|FL|62|0|S
3434344|-100000|20161108000000|GL|135|0|S
45454545|214|-2000|20161108000001||21|77440|S
```

With `awk`, courtesy @JamesBrown

```
$ awk '{gsub(/,[^|]*/,"")} 1' ip.txt 
12345343|559|-2|20161108000000|FL|62|0|S
3434344|-100000|20161108000000|GL|135|0|S
45454545|214|-2000|20161108000001||21|77440|S
```

or

```
$ awk 'gsub(/,[^|]*/,"")+1' ip.txt 
12345343|559|-2|20161108000000|FL|62|0|S
3434344|-100000|20161108000000|GL|135|0|S
45454545|214|-2000|20161108000001||21|77440|S
```

Comment: I was thinking too complicated at first too.. splitting into field, capturing, etc `perl -F'\|' -lane 's/([^,]*),.*/$1/ foreach @F; print join "|", @F'`

Comment: I like the +1 btw.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to get it done:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {i=0; while(++i<=NF) gsub(/,.*/,"",$i)}1' File
```

Output:

```
12345343|559|-2|20161108000000|FL|62|0|S
3434344|-100000|20161108000000|GL|135|0|S
45454545|214|-2000|20161108000001||21|77440|S
```

Comment: What does the 1 do at the end of the statement?

Comment: to print the record(each line in this case) without which only substitution would happen, but nothing would be printed.

Comment: Does the number actually signify anything?  I tried using 2 and 3 and the output was the same.  Wouldn't print $0 be more readable?

Comment: number doesn't signify anything.. any non-zero number would do